# How have icons/lines change color on scroll down using Jquery/CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to achieve the effect seen on this webpage:  http://gettalent.com

As you scroll down, you see that the icons (like the circular hammer icon, for instance), "lights up", i.e. it starts faded and then becomes more full with white as you scroll down.  The same goes for the lines that are connected to it and go down the page.

How would I go about achieving this for jquery and CSS?  I haven't found a solution after much searching.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the scroll height and alter the CSS via jQuery using the `.scroll()` event

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UR5wP/

Comment: is there a way to have it so there's a "smooth" transition?  As opposed to just reaching a height and changing completely (have it get slightly more opaque with scroll)

Comment: Try this new Fiddle, it will fade in the background for the first 50px of scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/UR5wP/4/